# Number of elements of order $11$ in group of order $1331$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $1331$. Prove that $G$ has at least $11$ elements of order $11$.

$|G|=1331=11^3$

So by First Sylow's theorem, there exists a Sylow $11$-subgroup of G.
By Third Sylow's theorem, the number of such subgroups is $11k+1$ and $11k+1|1331$, thus, this is only possible for $k=0$. This means that the Sylow $11$-subgroup is unique, and therefore there exist at least $10$ elements of order $11$ in $G$.

So it appears I'm missing one element to complete the proof. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ has more than one $11$-Sylow subgroups

Comment: The third theorem tells you that there exists a unique $11^3$-Sylow subgroup, which is completely obvious.

Comment: The question is wrong. The cyclic group of order $1331$ has only $10$ elements of order $11$.

Comment: By the way, it makes no sense to apply Sylow's Theorem to a group of order $p^n$ with $p$ prime, because it tells you nothing.

Comment: Are you *sure* the question does *not* say: prove $G$ has at least $11$ elements $g$ with $g^{11} = e$? Just sayin'.

Comment: Or perhaps prove that a non-cyciic group of that order has at least $11$ elements of order $11$. That is true, but not so easy to prove.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the remark of David Wheeler - in general, if $G$ is a group with $|G|=p^n$, $p$ prime, then $|\{g \in G : g^p=1 \}| \geq p$. This follows basically from Cauchy's Theorem.

By the way, in general it holds that $|\{g \in G : order(g)=p \}| \equiv -1$ mod $p$. This can be read off from the famous proof of James McKay (see for example [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/McKay%20Another%20Proof%20of%20Cauchy%27s%20Group%20Theorem.pdf)) of Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: Cauchy is not even needed as the only possible element orders are powers of $p$, so one gets one of order $p$ by considering powers (and then the result is a basic fact about cyclic groups).

Comment: @Tobias, yes thanks. True but my second fact is of general nature.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the remark of David Wheeler, so I'll read the question accordingly. Let $x\in G\setminus \{e\}$; then $o(x)=11^\alpha$, for some $\alpha\in\{1,2,3\}$ (Lagrange). But then $y:=x^{11^{\alpha-1}}$ has order $11$, and hence every element $g\in \langle  y\rangle$ fulfils $g^{11}=e$.